# Android sqlite behavior?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app with complicated database structure. When I use command "adb shell dumpsys meminfo [package name]", it shows information as followings:

DATABASES

```
  pgsz     dbsz   Lookaside(b)          cache  Dbname
     4       20             41       2/1514/3  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/a.db
     4      740             26     129/1375/2  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/b.db
     4       64             21       0/1409/1  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/c.db
     4       64             27       1/1408/2  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/c.db (3)
     4       64             57      12/1411/5  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/c.db (2)
     4       32             35      12/1514/3  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/d.db
     4       20             28      13/1381/2  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/e.db
     4       20             28       1/1513/2  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/f.db
     4       16             21       0/1514/1  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/g.db
     4    19164             84     124/1517/6  /data/user/0/[packagename]/databases/h.db
```

My questions are

1. why I get 3 c.db?
2. why number of middle cache value (cache miss-hit count?) are increased every seconds?

Thanks in advance!

Add:

I found out that when I using WAL mode and multiple threads to access database at the same time, it will create a lots connections until I call database.close() after accessing database. Are there any ideas how to handle it?

Comment: Can you share your Code? The open helpers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep this app private. Besides, it contains more than million lines of code. I do not even know which part should I share. :-(

Comment: Just the project structure would be fine too. How many open helpers do you have?